# Multiple validation in vb.net textbox

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox

The problem i am having is after checking if the field is blank i want program to stop at that, right now it is going ahead and checking the username password also even though the field is blank and printing wrong username password. i am really new at this so please excuse the lack of knowledge

```
Private Sub ButtonOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonOk.Click
    Try
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=stock;Data source=.;integrated security=true")
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet
        Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from login where Name='" & Trim(txtusername.Text) & "'and password='" & Trim(txtpassword.Text) & "'", con)


        If txtpassword.Text.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Password or username feild left blank")



        End If


        If da1.Fill(ds1) Then
            adminmain.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else

            MsgBox("Invalid Password or Username")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a web app or a desktop app? ASP.Net? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: @user1182892: Welcome on StackOverflow! You should accept the answer which helped you the most (by clicking on the checkmark next to it). You can also upvote any other answer which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Then [Return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the function.

```
If txtpassword.Text.Length = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Password or username feild left blank")
    Return
End If
```

But outside of the `Try/Catch` although it would work(a `finally-block` would be executed before the return statement). Actually the validation of the TextBox does not need to be inside of the `Try/Catch`, so imho it's confusing to return from within a Try/Catch.

Comment: omg it was that simple :O and i moved it outside try catch :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put your validations at the top of the Sub, and call `Exit Sub` as soon as an error is found.

```
Private Sub ButtonOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonOk.Click
    If txtpassword.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Password or username feild left blank")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Other validations here
    'Code to save changes here
End Sub
```

Also, you should remove that Try..Catch clause. If an unexpected error occurs you'll want to know what is the line number and stack trace of the error.